# Facebook login not updating session after redirect

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, session, facebook-php-sdk

I've been trying to use the Facebook PHP SDK with my CodeIgniter project. Logging in from the root/index page of my application works fine, however when I try to use the Facebook login on any other pages, the sessions don't update ($this->user returns 0) after redirecting from Facebook. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the **constructor** (where the login is handled) for the Controller for my application *(the appId and secret have been redacted here since they're somewhat sensitive info):*

```
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller {

public $USERID = 0; // used to be 1
var $fdb;

public $data_title = array();

public $user;
public $user_profile;
public $statusUrl;
public $loginUrl;
public $logoutUrl;

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $config['hostname'] = "localhost";
    $config['username'] = "root";
    $config['password'] = "";
    $config['database'] = "ranker";
    $config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
    $config['dbprefix'] = "";
    $config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $config['cachedir'] = "";
    $config['char_set'] = "utf8";
    $config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

    $this->fdb = $this->load->database('ranker', TRUE);
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('language');
    $this->lang->load('sitetext', $this->language->get());

    $fb_config = array(
        'appId'  => '<app id here>',
        'secret' => '<app secret here>'
    );
    $this->load->library('facebook',$fb_config);

    $this->user = $this->facebook->getUser();
    $this->USERID = $this->user;

    if ($this->user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $this->user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $this->user = null;
      }
    }

    // Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
    if ($this->user) {
      $this->logoutUrl= $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
      $this->statusUrl = $this->facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
      $this->loginUrl = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl();
    }
    $this->data_title['user'] = $this->user;
    $this->data_title['user_profile'] = $this->user_profile;
    $this->data_title['statusUrl'] = $this->statusUrl;
    $this->data_title['logoutUrl'] = $this->logoutUrl;
    $this->data_title['loginUrl'] = $this->loginUrl;
}
```

Facebook Login works ($this->user returns a non-zero value) for the Controller's **index()** method below:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('Queries');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['school_list'] = $this->Queries->get_select_school_list();

    $this->data_title['title_info'] = "";
    $this->load->view('header', $this->data_title);
    $this->load->view('search_box');
    $this->load->view('welcome_blurb');
    $this->load->view('list_select_schools',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

But the login doesn't update the session info after redirecting to and from Facebook when Facebook login is called from methods such as this one:

```
public function select_school()
{
    $this->load->model('Queries');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['school_list'] = $this->Queries->get_select_school_list();

    $this->data_title['title_info'] = "Select School | ";
    $this->load->view('header',$this->data_title);
    $this->load->view('list_select_schools',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Been scratching my head for the past couple of days. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you getting UserId from facebook after login? or its returning 0 ?

Comment: I can get UserId from facebook if redirect from the index() page, however it returns 0 when I redirect from other pages like select_school()